# Add "click" listener to google maps streetviewpanorama link?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to attach "click" event listener to StreetViewPanorama link?

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
var panorama = new.google.maps.StreetViewPanorama("someDomElement");

panorama.setPano('somePano');

google.maps.event.addListener(panorama.links[0], 'click', function () {
  some code;
});
```

The reason why I need this is to find out how pano was set: by clicking to links or by my code/handler.

thanks!

Comment: There is no option to attach events to these links.

Comment: I was afraid of that :) thanks for your comment. I decided to go with other method of tracking link click events.